# How can i parse/get from a textBox words that are only letters?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code I have in `form1` button event:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var words = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+)");
foreach (string word in words)
{
    ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(word.Trim());
    scrmbltb.GetText();
    sb.Append(word.Replace(word.Trim(), scrmbltb.scrambledWord));
}
textBox2.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

Im getting all the words as I wanted from `textBox1` but some of the words are also signs like `----` or `?` or `/` or `\n\r`

I want to parse/get only words that are built with letters.

How can I filter it?

I tried to do it this way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var words = Regex.Split(textBox1.Text, @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+\\w+)".Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value));
            var matches = Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, "\\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                ScrambleTextBoxText scrmbltb = new ScrambleTextBoxText(word.Trim());
                scrmbltb.GetText();
                sb.Append(word.Replace(word.Trim(), scrmbltb.scrambledWord));
            }
            textBox2.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

I need the var words since the Regex.Split there worked for me good with copy the spaces between textBox1 and textBox2.
So i tried to add the "\w+" and the .Cast().Select(match => match.Value
So it will be togeather in the variable words but im getting an error on the var words now:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(string, int)' has some invalid arguments

And

Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'int'

How can i solve it ?

I tried now this but it didnt work:

```
var words = Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+\\w+)").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);
```

Im getting no words at all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, "\\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);
```

should give you all words without empty strings.

whole code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var matches = Regex.Matches("Line 1 this is any random text. \r\n Line 2 Another Line?! \r\n Line 3 End of text. ", "\\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);
      foreach (string sWord in matches)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(sWord);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Koryu i just updated my question please take a look.

Comment: you only have to call the cast: ".Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value);" if you use Regex.Matches. if you use Regex.Split you dont need this. Its just to convert/cast the Matches to string

Comment: also notice that "\\w+" = @"\w+" so if you use @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+\\w+)" then it should be @"(?=(?<=[^\s])\s+\w+)" (whatever this statement does)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to do it with a Regex, and specifically want only letters, you could do this (matching rather than splitting):

```
var words = Regex.Matches(Test, @"[a-zA-Z]+");"
```

You may want `"[\w]+"` instead, as I suspect there will by some characters/digits that you're after.